# How can I dismiss notifications upon firing an intent on Android Wear?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm currently building a notification on the mobile device, and including a wear-specific intent to launch an activity. I want the notification to go away once the user hits that button on the notification, but I haven't gotten it to work. Here's my code

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        // Create the action
        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.buzz_icon_white,
                        "Respond with Buzz", pendingIntent)
                        .build();

        // Build the notification and add the action with WearableExtender
        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.buzz_icon_white)
                        .setContentTitle("Buzz")
                        .setContentText(name + ": " + message)
                        .extend(new WearableExtender().addAction(action))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setPriority(1)
                        .setVibrate(pattern)
                        .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        // Issue the notification with notification manager.
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add an extra to the Intent, and when the other Activity is in `onCreate`, check if it's the extra, and if so, delete the notification?

Comment: I think It's kind of bug. I use getIntent() to check if it is from wear and cancel it manually.  .setAutoCancel(true) do not seems be be working.